# Failure to download file from an Response in a HTTP handler

Tags: javascript, c#, html, download, httphandler

I am attempting to download a plain text file with a custom format through the HTTP response in a HTTPHandler. The file consists of numbers, letters and "|" as a delimiter. The file is being generated at runtime and is not being saved.

The handle is also being used to return data to a JavaScript function and thus the response cannot be closed when downloading the file.

Currently this is the code that is being used to download the file.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);
tw.Write(file1);
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
ms.Close();

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=file.15");
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();

context.Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = "true", message = "File1 Done", File1 = query["File1"], File2 = query["File2"] }));
```

However when this code is executed there are no errors (both server side and client side) and the file is not downloaded.

Comment: Why do you write to the response after closing and flushing it?

Comment: I am attempting to send data back to the javascript code on the .aspx page. As I am still relatively new to the way handlers and Requests/Responses work I am unsure how to do this as every example I have that prints a file either flushes, closes or/and ends the response. Thus I am having difficulty performing both tasks (download file and return data) using this handler.

Comment: You simply can't.

Comment: I see. This might be the reason why it would not seem to be working. The reason I was returning data was so that I could print 2 files using a single button press by using the response to print the first return then do another Ajax post to print the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that performing both actions using a handler is impossible (as noted in the comment by [Patrick Hofman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman)) since in order for the file to be downloaded using a response, the response has to be closed.

As a solution, the handler can write in the response the byte stream (or string) for the files and then proceed to download them via JavaScript.

Using the following code in the handler:

```
context.Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = "true", message = "File1 Done", File1 = File1, File2 = File2 }));
```

in order to return the data and then using this code in JavaScript:

```
function Download(response) {           
        DownloadFile("File1.15", response.File1);
        DownloadFile("File2.15", response.File2);         
    }
function DownloadFile(filename, data) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        }
        else {
            var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
            elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            elem.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(elem);
            elem.click();
            document.body.removeChild(elem);
        }
    }
```

to download the files.

This gives the possibility of downloading multiple files with a single handler call as well as return other information generated inside the handler (such as  success and message). The method Download is called upon the successful return of handler.

This does however require the site to have download multiple file privileges in the browser.